# Python 3 opening more than one .py program instead of just calling it in the same window

Tags: python-3.x

Hey i'm new here so if I've done something wrong i apologize. I have been searching for hours though and i figured i would just open a new question.
I want to have a python program that will open another window so it can display different information on that window whilst still displaying it's own information.
For ex: I have "hello.py" and it opens up another python window "goodbye.py"
i dont want what ever is in "goodbye.py" to show up on "hello.py" i want it to stay in its own window.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is to open 2 programs at the same time, couldn't you just open 2 **tabs** and open the 2 programs side by side like that? Ex. on mac, double click `open new window` and open a new tab.

Comment: Yes but i would like to do this from the other window... like "hello.py" opens up "goodbye.py" automatically